# How to read batch script variable in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmake

Hello to whoever reading this.

This is not actually a question. It's a problem i faced and i was trying to find solution here in stackoverflow. But i couldn't. [Chances are it may be duplicate in the eyes of experts]. Anyway thought i'll share the solution which is working for me.

**The Problem**

I work on Windows CE panels so in some scenario I need to read batch script variable in CMakeLists.txt to do some filtering based on whether it's Windows x86 or Windows CE. How to do that ?

Could be the same as [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690223/how-to-retrieve-a-user-environment-variable-in-cmake-windows) but for me export didn't work. So the whole picture.

Later checked export is in bash. In batch set will work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve a user environment variable in CMake (Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690223/how-to-retrieve-a-user-environment-variable-in-cmake-windows)

Comment: In a bigger picture Seems same.. but in my case export was not working :(

Answer (score 1):

The Answer which is working for me. [There are chance that other solution also exists but this worked for me]. Ok here it goes.

**In batch file**

```
set "PANEL_TYPE=WINCE"
```

In CMakeLists.txt

```
if( $ENV{PANEL_TYPE} STREQUAL "WINCE")
    message(STATUS "Print Message = " $ENV{PANEL_TYPE})
    set(THE STUFF)
else()
    message(STATUS "Other Message = " $ENV{PANEL_TYPE}) 
endif()
```

That's it. It seems simple to me and it worked :)

Comment: Can't you look at the standard environment variable `OS`?

Comment: Just a hint: That's probably not going to work with Visual Studio solutions. You have to transfer the environment variable into a cached variable in CMake. The reasoning: if Visual Studio runs in another environment, then each time in your project when CMake re-configures and re-generates the solution `$ENV{PANEL_TYPE}` would probably be empty.

Comment: Umm .. I am using it in Visual Studio. Not an expert in Cmake so can't actually say anything about it.

Comment: Touch one of your project's `CMakeLists.txt` files and build `ZERO_CHECK` target. What is the message's output of above example?

Comment: OK .. it's in windows.. So i give 1 space to modify (touch). The message is 

                    "Print Message = WINCE"

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I could but i needed to modify the CMakelist file to segregate the WINCE part and x86. So i needed something of my own which i can play with.