# Environment variable not found by cmake

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cmake, ros

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo and I need to use Geometry Tools Wild Magic 5 for developing a package.

I have exported the path to Wild Magic folder as an environment variable by modifying `.bashrc` as follows:

```
export WM5_PATH=/home/user/catkin_ws/src/GeometricTools/WildMagic5/SDK
```

This is done to specify locations of header files in the `CMakeLists.txt` file of the package I'm coding:

```
include_directories(
    include
    $ENV{WM5_PATH}/Include/
)
```

Previously, in the same cmake file I check if the environmental variable is correctly set:

```
if (NOT DEFINED ENV{WM5_PATH})
    MESSAGE (FATAL_ERROR "Wild Magic Engine 5.14 missing")
endif()
```

Now, while building the package using `catkin build` the environment variable is not found (the if above is entered). But by using `printenv` in the terminal I can see that the environment variable `WM5_PATH` is actually there.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just given your example a try and it works fine in my Ubuntu bash shell.

```
# export WM5_PATH=/home/user/catkin_ws/src/GeometricTools/WildMagic5/SDK
# cmake ..
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ...
```

So I suspect your `cmake` executable runs in another environment (e.g. an IDE).

To check what your CMake does see as an environment you could add the following to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E environment
)
```

**Reference**

- [How to retrieve a user environment variable in CMake (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690223/how-to-retrieve-a-user-environment-variable-in-cmake-windows)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I suppose what you say is correct: while I'm building the code using `catkin build` CMake sees the catkin environment as the current one. But, unfortunately if I add the portion of code you suggested to the `CMakeLists.txt` it does not print out anything in the terminal during `catkin build`! Do you know why?

Comment: @George CMake only runs/configures the build environment when you change/touch one of the `CMakeLists.txt` files. So no output from CMake would be normal, if you didn't change anything on the CMake side of the build.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very expert with CMake. I have changed the `CMakeLists.txt` by adding `execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E environment)` as you suggested. Would not that output the variables?

Comment: @George Yes, so it's [`catkin`](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_build.html): "Normally, unless an error occurs, the output from each package’s build process is collected but not printed to the console." So try `catkin build --verbose` to also see messages - like CMake's output - going to `stdout`.